# Why I cannot see the root folder of my website?

Tags: wordpress, server, webserver, ftp, document-root

I have a website hosted by Altervista on ComicPress theme. I purchased the second level domain, the URL is still `myblogname.altervista.org`.

I installed FileZilla client for entering the root folder of my website.

What I want is to create and copy a *php.ini* file for modyfing the size of files I upload.

FileZilla client and the configuration apparently works, that's what I get:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But where is the root directory of my website?

Comment: I do not use WP or any other CMS that I did not write myself. However, in your last image, in the bottom right panel, it appears that is your web root. I cannot tell you the full path. You will have to use FileZilla to tell you. But that looks like it! Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

Mate, you are in your web root.

```
wp-admin
wp-content
wp-includes
```

and rest of the files are the root directory of your WordPress.

Level above are rest of the pages on server. From what I see, you just have privilege to access that folder and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried clicking on the `..` in the right hand panel?  That indicates the parent directory.

If that doesn't work you will have to check with your web host, perhaps they have limited FTP access to your web facing directory rather than the home directory for your account - which usually has directories for mail and other services.

Answer (score 2):

The comment on your original post is correct, and I actually don't use any CMS I don't whip up myself either but if your new to WordPress to the best of my knowledge would output the 'theme' you activate when you navigate to your site, which is specified within the *style.css* file, in `wp-content/themes/` (your theme).

Then you can modify the theme you have activated. Probably not relevant information in regards to what your looking for (little hazing on what your asking) but thought I would offer a little guidance, just in case.